# Django REST, append new field from values in a list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In a **view**, I get the result of an image classifier as a dictionary containing the name of an animal as *key* and the probability of it being the correct animal as *value*.

```
{'dog': 0.9, 'wolf': 0.1}
```

From here I send a *Response* containing all the animals of the dictionary that are also in the Animal *Model*.

```
[
{
    'common_name': 'dog',
    'scientific_name' : 'Canis lupus familiaris',
},
]
```

I would like to add the probability value  for each occurrence contained in the dictionary :

```
[
{
    'common_name': 'dog',
    'scientific_name' : 'Canis lupus familiaris',
    'probability' : 0.9,

},
]
```

What would be the best strategy for that?

Here I am so far:

**Views.py**:

```
class AnimalListCreateAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        classifier_result={'dog': 0.9, 'wolf': 0.1}
        list_animals=list(classifier_result.keys())
        animals = Animal.objects.filter(common_name__in=list_animals)
        serializer = AnimalSerializer(animals, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializers.py**:

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model= Animal
        fields= [' common_name ',' scientific_name ']
```

**Models.py**

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    scientific_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self. common_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this way. I'm sure there is another

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    probability = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model= Animal
        fields= ['common_name','scientific_name', 'probability']

    def get_probability(self, obj):
        return self.context['probability'].get(obj.common_name)

...


serializer = AnimalSerializer(animals, many=True, context={'probability': classifier_result})
```